# Check which filters have been applied to a collection

Tags: collection, zend-framework

Is it possible to check which filters have been applied to a given collection.

For example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('state', 'processing');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('status', 'processing2');
```

I want to get an array of all filters applied at this point:

```
array(
    'state' => 'processing',
    'status' => 'processing2'
)
```

The closest i can get so far seems to be:

```
$collection->getSelect()->getPart('where');
```

But this is not exactly what I am looking for as it does also provide the AND etc.

For example:

```
array(2) {
    [0] => string(22) "(state = 'processing')"
    [1] => string(28) "AND (status = 'processing2')"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As you can see in `\Varien_Data_Collection_Db::addFieldToFilter` there is no way to achieve what you want, out of the box:

```
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
{
    if (!is_array($field)) {
        $resultCondition = $this->_translateCondition($field, $condition);
    } else {
        $conditions = array();
        foreach ($field as $key => $currField) {
            $conditions[] = $this->_translateCondition(
                $currField,
                isset($condition[$key]) ? $condition[$key] : null
            );
        }

        $resultCondition = '(' . join(') ' . Zend_Db_Select::SQL_OR . ' (', $conditions) . ')';
    }

    $this->_select->where($resultCondition);

    return $this;
}
```

Because the filter is translated to a where condition and added to the `Zend_Db_Select` object.

You can change the collection to use the `protected $_filters = array();` property instead of applying the filters directly, then you can just get the filter, if you have access to this property.

This works, because `\Varien_Data_Collection_Db::load` calls `\Varien_Data_Collection_Db::_renderFilters`.

Comment: yes,there are no way to achieve it.Thanks for your descrtion